# multipass moving data directory fail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines, multipass

I am following:

https://github.com/canonical/multipass/pull/1789 and https://lucasroesler.com/posts/2020/multipass-data-partition/ to move MULTIPASS_STORAGE to another location, but I am not lucky.

I am setting MULTIPASS_STORAGE=/pendrive/multipass:

/etc/systemd/system/snap.multipass.multipassd.service.d/override.conf

```
[Service]

Environment=MULTIPASS_STORAGE=/pendrive/multipass
```

If I run sudo journalctl -au snap.multipass* I get: Caught an unhandled exception: unable to create directory '/pendrive/multipass/cache'

This is my owner and permission (ls -l):

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root multipass 4096 mar 28 22:27 multipass
```

I have my removable mount point like this: /dev/sdb1 /pendrive If I try sudo snap connect multipass:/pendrive I got error: snap "multipass" has no plug named "/pendrive"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the `snap` confinment and `Multipass`, it cant access the `/pendrive` directory.

Here is how to fix this: first be sure that Multipass is connected `sudo snap connect multipass:removable-media` then update the file `/etc/systemd/system/snap.multipass.multipassd.service.d/override.conf` to use the `/media` instead with this

```
[Service]
Environment=MULTIPASS_STORAGE=/media/pendrive/multipass
```

then set the correct permissions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/pendrive/multipass
sudo chown root:multipass /media/pendrive/multipass
sudo chmod 775 /media/pendrive/multipass
```

then Update your `/etc/fstab` file to mount the pendrive under the `/media` directory: `/dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive ...`

then replace the ellipsis with the good mount options for your filesystem and restart with this, then this should work:

```
sudo umount /pendrive
sudo mount /media/pendrive
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart snap.multipass.multipassd.service
```

Comment: It is very necesary to put my mount point /pendrive bellow /media ? because I should have to change a lot of think not related with multipass

Comment: I implemented you recommend me and it works fine. Thank you

Comment: You welcome :) dont forget to accept the question if it solved your problem, also it is not necessary to put your mount point /pendrive below /media